# How to get the last exception object after an error is raised at a Python prompt?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, read-eval-print-loop

When debugging Python code at the interactive prompt (REPL), often I'll write some code which raises an exception, but I haven't wrapped it in a `try`/`except`, so once the error is raised, I've forever lost the exception object.

Often the traceback and error message Python prints out isn't enough. For example, when fetching a URL, the server might return a 40x error, and you need the content of the response via `error.read()` ... but you haven't got the error object anymore. For example:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/api/?foo=bad-query-string')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Drat, what did the body of the response say? It probably had valuable error information in it...

I realize it's usually easy to re-run your code wrapped in a try/except, but that's not ideal. I also realize that in this specific case if I were using the `requests` library (which doesn't raise for HTTP errors), I wouldn't have this problem ... but I'm really wondering if there's a more general way to get the last exception object at a Python prompt in these cases.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The `sys` module provides some functions for post-hoc examining of exceptions: [`sys.last_type`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.last_type), [`sys.last_value`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.last_value), and [`sys.last_traceback`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.last_traceback).

`sys.last_value` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: @BenHoyt FYI, according to the documentation of `sys`, "These three are only available in an interactive session after a traceback has been printed. ".

Comment: @satoru Well, obviously. In a normal program, an unhandled exception will terminate the program.

Comment: I had to search a bit to find the right code to print all these correctly using traceback module. Here it is if any one needed:
```traceback.print_exception(etype=sys.last_type,value=sys.last_value,tb=sys.last_traceback)```

Answer (score 34):

As @Cairnarvon mentioned, I didn't find any `last_value`member is sys module.

`sys.exc_info()` did the trick for me. `sys.exc_info()` returns a tuple with three values `(type, value, traceback)`.

So `sys.exc_info()[1]` will give the readable error. Here is the example,

```
import sys
list = [1,2,3,4]
try:
    del list[8]
except Exception:
    print(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

will output `list assignment index out of range`

Also, `traceback.format_exc()` from `traceback` module can be used to print out the similar information.

Below is the output if `format_exec()` is used,

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: This is the answer to a different question. `sys.exc_info` only returns useful information while you're inside an except clause; the question was asking about getting information about the last exception *after* it's already fired.

Answer (score 1):

The `sys.last_type`, `sys.last_value`, and `sys.last_traceback` variables are not always defined. Actually, they are intended to be used in an interactive session. I was able to get the last raised exception using [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). Usage:

```
import sys
ex_type, ex_value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
```

The last raised exception object will be stored in `ex_value`