# How to "Run all cells above" in VS Code's Python Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-python

Is there a way to run all cells above a given cell in VS Code's python notebook working environment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the command pallet run the command: `Notebook: Execute Above Cells`.
Create a keyboard shortcut (e.g., `alt+A`). Then you are done.

Comment: cmd+shift+p to access the command pallet on windows. Then ensure that you're in code cell so you can see the command. Thanks Jae